# PHPunit 9.23 PHP 7.4.7 Warning no test found in class

Tags: phpunit

I'm trying to write some test using PHPUNit but somehow the tests can't be recognized when I try to run .\vendor\bin\phpunit.
Here is an example of my Test class

```html
use \App\Controllers\city_controller;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class city_controllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
     public function test_AddCity(){
      $this->assertTrue(true);
     }
}
```

I always receive the "Warning No tests found in class".
Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the doc the method name must start by "test".

I'd rename `test_AddCity()` by `testAddCity()`

And your class to `TestCityController`

Hope that'll work form you as it did for me!